# Find occurrences of numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to compare a list containing a sequence of numbers and a python dictionary in order to find occurrences of numbers.
The behaviour of program:

- The function occurences(L) takes as parameter a list
- The function occurences(L) returns a dictionary whose keys are the elements of the list and the values are the number of times the element appears.

```
liste = []

def occurrences(liste):
    dico = {}
    for i in liste:
        for k,v in dico.items():
            if i == liste[k]:
                dico[i] = dico[i] + 1 
            else:
                dico[i] = 1
    return dico
```

Example of result:

```
>>> occurrences([1,3,2,1,4,1,2,1]) # input
{1:4,2:2,3:1,4:1} # output
```

Comment: And... what's the question? Problem with the code? Something not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for an easier/more pythonic way to do this, I suggest looking at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass from the `collections` library. All you would have to do to achieve your desired result is:

```
from collections import Counter
liste = [1,3,2,1,4,1,2,1]
n_occurences = Counter(liste) # returns {1:4,2:2,3:1,4:1}, which is 
                              # the same thing as your function occurences(liste)
```

Comment: Also of note:  `len(Counter(liste))` is the number of unique values in the list, although you could get the same information with `len(set(liste))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{i:liste.count(i) for i in set(liste)}
```